# Plotting graphs on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

This VBA Code

Enables me to insert at will to insert a bloc of 3 columns that contains costs of 2 projets + a total and the date is inserted automatically on the day the button (the lowest one) is pressed, then I fill the new bloc with recent informations from columns A to D it's basic info, from D to Q (currently) are all sets of similar blocs with different data. I would like to use the highest button to plot the change of cost over time of the 2 projets seperately and the total as well on the same graph using VBA code, keeping in mind that I'm always going to insert new data and it needs to be included on the sheet as well. My attempt of coding chooses all the data from the spreadsheet and plots them, so my question is how can I choose particular cells from the spreadsheet keeping in mind that I will always add new cells?
The code that enables me to insert new bloc set :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const CaptionRow    As Long = 14
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim Cl              As Long
Dim Chart1          As Chart

With Worksheets("Tableau des couts")
    Cl = Cells(CaptionRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Columns(Cl - 2).Resize(, 3).Copy
    Cells(1, Cl + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(CaptionRow + 1, Cl + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Cl + 2).End(xlUp))
    On Error Resume Next
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
End With
Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 3).Select
Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 3).ClearContents
Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 3).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Sub
```

And my attempt of code to plot the data required :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Const CaptionRow    As Long = 14
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim Cl              As Long
Dim Chart1          As Chart
With Worksheets("Tableau des couts")
Cl = Cells(CaptionRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
Chart1.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Tableau des couts").Range(Cells(CaptionRow + 1, Cl + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Cl + 2).End(xlUp)).CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlColumns
Chart1.ChartType = xl3DLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Your With block `With Worksheets("Tableau des couts")` has no `End With` (indicating to me that you never tried the code that error would be flagged immediately) and no linked objects. Link objects with a leading period. `Cells(CaptionRow, Columns.Count)` is a cell on the ActiveSheet (sheet unspecified). `.Cells(CaptionRow, .Columns.Count)` is a cell on Worksheets("Tableau des couts"). Observe that the columns are also counted here or there depending on the leading period.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do but if the idea is to use data from every 3rd column in a range to create a chart you can't specify the entire range as a data source. You should first create an array, picking a number from each third column, and then base your chart on that array.

Comment: Hey Var, it’s always a pleasure to see your comments, for the code I am sorry for being dumb I must have erased it while copying the code and editing the thread but I did try my code, after all it was my attempt.
What I’m trying to do exactly is plot 3 curves on the same graph sheet first graph would be x axis : dates y axis the number under C15P for all the blocs that are already inserted and would be inserted in the future, second graph x axis : dates y axis the number under C15 and finally the 3rd graph x axis : dates y axis the number under total.

Comment: What I can’t seem to figure out, for example let’s take the first curve I want to plot, I would need the code to find a way to skip cells so it can always choose the cells that contain dates on my blocs, same for the numbers that are always relative to C15P, then plot them as a curve that represent the evolution of those numbers per date of insertion. That is what I can’t get my hands under. I hope I expressed it more clearly now

Answer (score 0):

As I said, Nassim, the data have to be extracted into 3 arrays and then each extracted array can be used to plot one line. Here is code to extract the data. As you know, with my code the constants at the top are the key which need to be understood exactly.

```
Function DataArray(ByVal GrpClm As Long) As Variant
    ' GrpClm specifies which column in a group to be added to the array

    Const DataRow       As Long = 3         ' set to suit or make it variable
    Const FirstDataClm  As Long = 3         ' 3 would be column C
    Const GroupSize     As Long = 3         ' set to suit
    
    Dim Fun             As Variant          ' preparing the arrays to be returned
    Dim Arr             As Variant          ' all data
    Dim C               As Long             ' loop counter: column
    Dim n               As Long             ' elements of Fun
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change to the name of your worksheet
        ' reading data from the array is faster than reading them from the sheet one by one
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(DataRow, 1), .Cells(DataRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
    End With
    
    ReDim Fun(1 To UBound(Arr, 2))
    C = FirstDataClm + GrpClm - 1
    For C = C To UBound(Arr, 2) Step GroupSize
        n = n + 1
        Fun(n) = Arr(1, C)
    Next C
    
    ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To n)
    DataArray = Fun
End Function
```

The function presumes that you have all data in one row. So you need to define the `DataRow`. There may be some row captions on the left. So the first relevant column, `FirstDataClm`, must be defined. Finally, if you want to extract every nth value the `GroupSize` must be specified. That will be n.

Now, the function returns only one array. It might be any one in the Group: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th but not higher than *GroupSize*, of course. This information is given to the function as a parameter from the calling procedure. In this way you can use the same function to extract aany of the arrays, one after another.

Here is an example of the function call. It's designed for your testing, not really for your use, because that wouldn't be in response to your present question.

```
Private Sub Test()
    
    Dim Arr         As Variant
    Dim i           As Long
    
    Arr = DataArray(2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This call will return an array of the second columns of each group in the data row and print the values for you in the Immediate pane so that you can check them. When you inspect such results pay attention to the first and last values which are easy to get dropped when the loop is adjusted. If first and last are correct the middle can hardly be wrong, however many entries there might be.

BTW, the term `.Cells(DataRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` when reading the data from the sheet ensures that the most recent columns are included. But do remember to change the tab's name in the code to the name of your own sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Variatus, this might be by far the hardest code I encountered so I might need some time to understand it